# Eevee - Baking soft shadows

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I have a question about soft shadow option in eevee. Is there a way to bake them in eevee?
What is a problem - when I turn on soft shadow option it instances light depending on it size, and it looks nice but I need atleast 1000 eevee samples to make them look good and soft and well its not an option in Eevee(it will be faster in cycles). So my question is how to manage that to render everything with 32-64 samples which gave me results I want but shadow setup much higher or bake them that I will not waste time and calculating power. Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to bake indirect lighting in Eevee. Have you ever tried using **irradiance volumes**? They're in the light probes menu when you add a mesh. The basic concept is that the specific lighting contitions are baked within the boundaries of the irradiance volume. You can scale it up if you want, and increase it's resolution, but I wouldn't go over 20, seems like overkill to me, but if you want to test it, don't hold back. **To bake it** you go to the render tab, and click "**Bake indirect lighting**" under the "**Indirect lighting**" tab

Comment: Yes, I have archviz scene and it not solve the problem - its baking propagation of light that give this nice look to whole interior but shadows are still independent and not baked